# No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Object

Tags: java, validation, generics

I'm using the `javax.validation` API in my project and have the titular problem on some of developer machines and on the test server. On other developer machines this bug can't be reproduced despite the fact that we are using the same Glassfish version, IDE and library stack handled by maven.

While debugging this problem we suspected something that may be the cause of the problem (we can't debug inside compiled classes, therefore 'suspected') - we have an interface for our persistable entities:

```
public interface PersistableEntity<T> {

    public T getId();

    public void setId(T id);
}
```

Implementation classes are split by 'id' field type: `String` or `BigDecimal`. The `@Pattern` constraint is attached to the getter of the `id` field in the `PersistableEntity<String>` implementation.

If this is the cause, is it possible to maintain validation using `javax.validation` and use generics in the same time?

**Update**
We decided to move from JSR303 to custom configurable validation mechanism. If someone with titular problem finds it's solution, please let me know which one it is, and I'll mark it as an answer (any other solutions to this dilema from experienced SO users are welcome).

Comment: Could you provide an entity that implements this PersistableEntity interface? ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))

Comment: @sp00m, we have big hierarchy tree for persistable entities, and at the end there are relatively large POJO classes, it will be hard to list down those here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually using the [`Persistable`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html) interface of Spring Data, but the idea seems to be the same as your custom one.

Let's say my `user` table has two fields: `user_id` (PK) and `email` (NN). The JAVA `User` entity will then have a `getUserId()` getter and a `getEmail()` one.

When implementing the `Persistable` interface, a `getId()` getter must be overridden, while the table `user` doesn't contain an `id` field. You can explicitly tell JAVA that the corresponding table doesn't contain such a field by using the [`@Transient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Persistable<Integer> {

    // Persistable implementation

    @Override
    @Transient // <-- means "not a database field"
    public Integer getId() {
        return getUserId();
    }

    // user_id

    @Column(name = "user_id", precision = 10)
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    // email

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

}
```

Maybe this could solve your problem.

Comment: This problem is outdated now, but anyway thank you :) I think other people with same problem will find your answer helpful.